# how to stop resubmiting the page on referesh in asp.net web forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

How can we prevent resubmitting the page on refresh..

For Example: 
I have an input field and on submitting the page it adds the value of that field to a list and gets reloaded automatically but if intentionaly refresh the page without writing anything to the field it adds the previously added value to the list. How to prevent this problem in webforms asp.net

Comment: A POST ist a POST and a GET is a GET. I think that you cannot change the refresh behaviour of a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<input type="button" />` instead of `<input type="submit" />` or their corresponding ASP.NET controls. If you have a submit button on the page, it will post the form when you refresh (regardless of whether is accidental or intentional). But you lose the ability to submit the form using the enter button. The user has to click on the input button.

You might still want to keep the submit button, so in that case after adding to the list, redirect to the URL explicitly using Response.Redirect

```
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
```

In addition, to be totally fail-safe on the server side, you can also check if the item already exists in the list or the database (if that's the backing store for the list) before adding it.

Comment: but i am usning 

<asp:Button ID="sendToQueue" runat="server" Text="Send To Queue" OnClick="sendToQueue_Click" />

instead of

 <input type="button"/>

Comment: <asp:Button /> by default generates an <input type="submit" /> unless you set another attribute UseSubmitBehavior=false.